# get main function name when nested function is running - in python

Tags: python, python-3.x, function

I am trying to get the name of main function that is called. I mean the case when I run main function (`updating.new_cycle`) and in some conditions other function (`inserting.inserting_data_ts`) is running, via import from inserting.py file.

My code:

```
updating.new_cycle(new,
                   old,
                   db, '2018-09-13')
```

In function `new_cycle`:

```
for i in list(new):
    if i not in old:
        import inserting            
        newdata = {u'type': u'FeatureCollection', u'features': new[i]}
        inserting.inserting_data_ts(new, TimeBegin, None)
```

So, I want to catch this condition is proceeded: when `inserting_data_ts` is called from updating.new_cycle (when main calling function is `updating.new_cycle`, not `inserting.inserting_data_ts`).

How can I achieve this?

Comment: Totally unrelated, but using `ast.literal_eval` to create a dict is a complete WTF. What's wrong with `newdata =  {u'type': u'FeatureCollection', u'features': str(new[i])}` ?

Comment: I fixed, thank you for advice

Answer (score 0, accepted):

#### Be explicit

> So, I want to catch this condition is proceeded: when
>   inserting_data_ts is called from updating.new_cycle

Just add an extra variable to your function, something like:

```
inserting.inserting_data_ts(new, TimeBegin, None, origin_flag=True)
```

Then define `inserting_data_ts` with an additional keyword argument `origin_flag` defaulting to `False`.